# How to pass "read-only" props in SolidJS

Tags: solid-js

I frequently pass properties to Solid components that are read-only for dependency injection of singleton services. See the simplified example below. However the SolidJS lint rules give me errors like: `The reactive variable 'props.firestore' should be used within JSX, a tracked scope (like createEffect), or inside an event handler function.` It seems totally reasonable to have some readonly props like this. Am I misusing props in SolidJS or not understanding something? Or are the ESLint rules not sophisticated enough? I can disable the lint warnings but don't want to do that if I'm doing something wrong here.

```
export const DocumentView = (props: { firestore: Firestore }) => {
  const query = query(collection(props.firestore), "my-collection");
  const [docs, setDocs] = createSignal([]);
  const unsubscribeQuery = onSnapshot(query, (snapshot) => {
    setDocs(() => snapshot);
  });
  onCleanup(() => unsubscribeQuery());
  return (
    <div>
      <For each={docs}>{(i) => <p>{i}</p>}</For>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: When you say "read only" I think you mean "not meant to update after the component renders", in which case you are correct that the linter rule can be ignored. It's a useful rule because people may expect something to happen when the prop value changes, yet nothing will happen. However, if you don't need anything to happen when the prop changes (such as if it will never change), then you are safe to ignore the rule. (general suggestion: feel free to ignore the (lint) rules if you understand them and why they don't apply)

Comment: Ok. Its just that I am trying to follow a good well-known pattern - dependency injection - and the ESLint rule was telling me I'm doing something wrong - which made me question whether I am using Solid correctly.

Comment: The problem is that people will use a prop to initialize a signal, and then be surprised when the signal doesn't update to match the prop. That's why this rule exists, so if you use a prop outside of a reactive context you'll get a warning. The purpose _is_ to make those people question whether they're using solid correctly. Perhaps open an issue on the plugin repo for more documentation on when to ignore warnings?

Answer (score 0):

When the components compiled, props becomes the function arguments and they are passed as is. So, if you pass readonly values to a component, they will remain readonly.

```js
import { Component } from 'solid-js';

export const DocumentView: Component<any> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{JSON.stringify(props.o)}</div>
  );
};
```

```js
import { template as _$template } from "solid-js/web";
import { insert as _$insert } from "solid-js/web";
const _tmpl$ = /*#__PURE__*/_$template(`<div></div>`, 2);
import { Component } from 'solid-js';

export const DocumentView = props => {

  return (() => {
    const _el$ = _tmpl$.cloneNode(true);
    _$insert(_el$, () => JSON.stringify(props.o));
    return _el$;
  })();
};
```

Now, the problem with your code is using untracked reactive variables. By untract, we mean its dependencies can not be tracked by the Solid's runtime.

Solid tracks effects by creating a data structure where the inner scope will be owned by an outer scope, and this chain goes all the way up to the `render` function. That is why you get an error like below when you create effects outside this hierarchy.

```bash
SolidJS: "computations created outside 
a `createRoot` or `render` will never be disposed."
```

This is for preventing memory leaks by releasing any resource created by an effect. You can read more about owners:

https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#runwithowner

However this check targets the untracked effects, not signals. So you can access signals anywhere, doesn't matter scope is tracked or not:

The related eslint rule limits the accessing of signals to the tracked scopes, probably as a safety measure.

```bash
"The reactive variable '{{name}}' should be used within JSX,
a tracked scope (like createEffect),
or inside an event handler function.",
```

This means you can use signal values inside a tracked scope. So, disabling the rule should not have any effect on how your components run.